# How do I include array positions in a switch-case statement?

Tags: c#, arrays, switch-statement

I need to include array positions, like position [0], position [1], etc. into a switch-case.

I'm new to programming, and I'm starting with C#, so I tried to create a very simple array for this switch statement, but everything I've tried hasn't been working. This is what I have so far:

```
                string[] wordme = { "me", "myself", "i" };
                switch (wordme)
                {
                    case wordme[0]:
                        Me("me"); //refers to method
                        continue;
                    case wordme[1]:
                        Myself("myself"); //refers to method
                        continue;
                    case wordme[2]:
                        I("i");//refers to method
                        continue;
                    default:
                        continue;

                }
```

I expected it to reference the methods, but instead it won't run because of 3 error messages, all referring to the "case" lines, reading, "Cannot Implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]'"

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you wanting to read a word from somewhere then switch based on whether it is any of the words in the array?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure completely what you are trying to do, or why you need to do it. However, you could use the [when contextual keyword](http://when%20(C#%20Reference))

> Starting with C# 7.0, case labels no longer need be mutually
>   exclusive, and the order in which case labels appear in a switch
>   statement can determine which switch block executes. The when keyword
>   can be used to specify a filter condition that causes its associated
>   case label to be true only if the filter condition is also true

```
string[] wordme = { "me", "myself", "i" };

for (int i = 0; i < wordme.Length; i++)
{
   switch (wordme[i])
   {
      case "me" when i == 0:
         Me("me"); //refers to method
         break;
      case "myself" when i == 1:
         Myself("myself"); //refers to method
         break;
      case "i" when i == 2:
         I("i"); //refers to method
         break;
      default:
         break;

   }
}
```

Or another guess

```
string[] wordme = { "me", "myself", "i" };

var mapping = new Dictionary<(string key, int ID), Action<string>> { 
       {("me", 0), s => Me(s)},
       {("myself", 1), s => Myself(s)},
       {("i", 2), s => I(s) }};

for (var i = 0; i < wordme.Length; i++)
   if (mapping.TryGetValue((wordme[i], i), out var action))
      action(wordme[i]);
```

Comment: I haven't a clue what the OP is trying to do either, but I doubt very much it's what you've posted...

Comment: @KenY-N , yeah the question is a mystical jar of wonderment, though my assumption is its some sort of sequential parser (guess)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this Way !! 
foreach (var item in wordme)Console.WriteLine(item);